# Call javascript method on alert button click

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-notifications

I have to call a javascript method on OK clicked from an alert created in java plugin. Actually the alert is displayed on click of the notification from the status bar.

// Method to collect info from pending intent on notification click

```
 public void launchNotification()
    {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent!=null)
        {
        if(intent.getExtras().getBoolean("fromNotification"))
        {
        final String notificationType = intent.getStringExtra("notificationType");
        final String twoWeeksNotificationType = intent.getStringExtra("2WeeksNotificationType");
        final String tasksNotificationType = intent.getStringExtra("tasksNotificationType");

        if(notificationType != null || twoWeeksNotificationType != null || tasksNotificationType != null)
        {
            if(notificationType != null && notificationType.equals("dailyReviewAvailable"))
            {
                NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nMgr.cancel("DailyReview", 0);

                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(
                        new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                showAlertForNotifications(notificationType);
                            }
                        }, 1000L);

            }
        intent.putExtra("fromNotification",false);
        }
        else
            finish();
        }
    }
```

// Method for launching alert after notification is clickedpublic void

```
showAlertForNotifications(String notificationIdStr) {

        if(notificationIdStr.equals("dailyReviewAvailable")) {

            Log.d("Notification", "Daily Review Start");                 

            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            adb.setTitle("Actions Hero");
            adb.setMessage("Would you like to send your daily review?");

            adb.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                {
                                        showDailyReview();
                }
            });

            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                {
                    // Action for 'Cancel' Button
                    dialog.cancel();
                    finish();
                }
            });
            //adb.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            adb.show();

        }
        else {
            //do later
        }

    }
```

// Method to call javascript function on OK click of alert button in java

```
        public void showDailyReview() {

        Log.v("showDailyReview", "Before");
// This javascript function cannot be invoked       super.sendJavascript("javascript:app.runningDailyReview('DailyReview')");
        Log.v("showDailyReview", "After");

        finish();

    }
```

How should I invoke the javascript method on clicking OK on the alert shown ??
Thanks..

Comment: But the same method can be called if I call it in alert created by my launcher class in java

Comment: I mean if I use the above code in main launcher class in android plugin. then it is perfectly called .. but doing the same in another class in android doesn't call it.. Dnt knw y ??